# After installing react-native-firebase/app it's Build will failed in react-native ios

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

After installing `react-native-firebase/app@15.3.0` with `react-native-0.68.1` using `use_frameworks!` and remove `flipper`in the podfile of the project , but when i ran `npx react-native run-ios` it's Build failed

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-gvnovwrlbjvxedcquaumtvgvdgmn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-razorpay/react_native_razorpay.framework/react_native_razorpay normal (in target 'react-native-razorpay' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure) , The Project also contain `react-native-razorpay` previously added ..now what to do for removing the error and build will succeed with out any crash, Please help i am new to react-native
my podfile looks like ``` #use_modular_headers!

require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'DussriShadi' do

## use_frameworks!

config = use_native_modules!

## Flags change depending on the env values.

flags = get_default_flags()

use_react_native!(
:path => config[:reactNativePath],
# to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
:hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
:fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
# An absolute path to your application root.
:app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
)

target 'DussriShadiTests' do
inherit! :complete
# Pods for

end

## Enables Flipper.

## Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and

## you should disable the next line.

#use_flipper!()

post_install do |installer|
react_native_post_install(installer)
__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
end
end

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build folder. Maybe also try deleting and re-installing the pods.
Since the error is related to ```DerivedData``` folder, also try deleting the derived data folder for xcode

Comment: TRY 1: REMOVE POD AND AGAIN INSTALL POD.
///// OR  ////
TRY 2: CLEAR ALL DATA FROM YOUR DERIVEDDATA FOLDER,  FURTHER REMOVE POD AND AGAIN INSTALL POD.

Comment: I'm getting the same from fresh vanilla install of RN app and RNFirebase. Tried various versions of RN and followed the instructions to the letter.  My 14.9 project works fine.

Comment: yes , it was fine in react-native-firebase v14..but not in v15+

Answer (score 15):

This is what worked for me using

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.6.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.6.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.1"
```

1. first add this into podfile:

   ```
     pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
     pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
   ```

in between

```
   flags = get_default_flags()
```

and

```
   use_react_native!(
```

2. Then delete podfile.lock.
3. Then do:

   ```
     cd ios
     pod deintegrate
     pod cache clean --all
     npm cache verify
     yarn cache clean
     pod install --repo-update
   ```
4. Then clean build folder under XCode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder.
5. Then run from within XCode.

Comment: genius...I spent hours on this. this finally fixed it. thanks!

Comment: If you find yourself here in 2023, do yourself a favour and delete any changes you might have made prior to seeing this answer. Then, follow exactly the steps mentioned in this answer.

Comment: This worked for me too. God bless you for your help!

Comment: Hi there! This is not a configuration that will be supported in react-native-firebase. It happens to work now but will likely break in the future, and already breaks if you use Storage or other modules that rely on pure `use_frameworks` behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved by commenting the use_frameworks! line and then added manually all the pods necessary for Firebase. This are the setting of my Podfile.

RN: "0.71.8"
Firebase: "18.0.0"

````
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
deployment_target = '13.0'
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'real_trends' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  # use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'real_trendsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I'd like to use Flipper and RNFirebase :)

Comment: Hi there! I am the react-native-firebase maintainer.

Flipper is deprecated and will be removed from react-native.
Adding each pod individually is an unsupportable configuration for react-native-firebase
Using "modular_headers" is an unsupportable configuration for react-native-firebase

Do not use these recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Adding pods with modular headers (as Charlotte_Anne) do truly work but it is important **NOT** to use

`use_frameworks!`

Do not place use_frameworks! in podfile (although firebase installation instructions tell you to do so)
And it works!
Also encountered different problems after rebuilding (appregistry not found etc) which have many false solutions/answers and it still didnt work. What worked for me is to rebuild the project from git (git clone original project, modify podfile, pod install).

Comment: Hi there! I am the react-native-firebase maintainer. The only supported configuration for react-native-firebase is to add `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`. You must use it, or you will not be on a supported configuration and any problems you have are yours alone.

Answer (score 0):

The steps outlined [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833305/1591099) are still relevant with the newest versions:

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.10",
```

My only issue, after I had done all the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833305/1591099), was that the app would crash with:

> Error: [app/unknown] Default app has already been configured.

It turned out that this was because I had the `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the Xcode project, as well as having initialized Firebase in the RN project.

```js
import {firebaseConfig} from './firebaseConfig';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

The issue disappeared after I deleted the `GoogleService-Info.plist` from the Xcode project.

I'm not quite sure why the react-native-firebase official guides do not align with reality.