# npx react-native run-ios build fails, but build succeeds in Xcode

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-cli

This is an app that has been building both on the command line and in Xcode I have  that stopped building on the command line. It happened awhile ago and I have just been using Xcode, but now I would like to fix it. Here is the immediate message:

```
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/susancrayne/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Text911MobileApp-ftkbgymgncgaiockqfauwqqagvom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-337605CB7CDF90939BEBF863ED22C375.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
```

Here is my Podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Text911MobileApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'react-native-sms', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sms'

  target 'Text911MobileAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  pre_install do |installer|
    $RNMBGL.pre_install(installer)
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    $RNMBGL.post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS'] = '-DDONT_AUTOINSTALL_REANIMATED'
          config.build_settings["CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY"] = ""
      end
  end

  end

end
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Text911MobileApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.4",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.53",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.2",
    "react-native-alert-async": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-egg": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.24",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-sms": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.15.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I have cleared the cache, npm install, pod install thing, without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416469/after-installing-react-native-firebase-app-its-build-will-failed-in-react-nativ?rq=2
I involves modifying the podfile.